Query maxim device studio live variables on MAX86150EVKIT
I am using the MAX86150EVKIT to do some research.  I want to be able to query the dynamic values in real time.  My idea was to query the log file as the board monitors PPG, GUI as follows:

Unfortunately, the log file is only written once the monitoring is stopped whereas I want to monitor the value over 5 minutes and react if certain criteria are set.
The help documentation is very limited consisting of two files that describe installation and GUI operation (DeviceStudio_Help.doc and ECPPG_EVKit_Help.doc).
There is also a raise access level option:

It looks for me to 'Enter internal user password'

Is there any documentation on how to raise the access level?
Presumably, if the values are not being written they are being stored either in memory or on disk so it should be possible to acces them.
Does anyone know how I can query the Maxim Device Studio (MAX86150EVKIT) monitoring values via a different program?
